# Box border animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, animation

How do I implement the following box border animation in this code pen automatically when the user opens the page rather than it only functioning on the click of a mouse.

https://codepen.io/joshlondon/pen/jbwMdd

Here is the relevant code from this code pen.

```js
$(document).ready(function(e) {
  
  $('.box').on('click', function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('is-selected');
  })
  
});
```

```css
@keyframes lineFillHorz {
  from {
    width: 0;
  } to {
    width: 100%;
  }
}

@keyframes lineFillVert {
  from {
    height: 1px;
  } to {
    height: 100%;
  }
}

.box {
  border: 1px solid #ececec;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: block;
  width: 400px;
  height: 260px;
  margin: 2em auto;
  position: relative;
  
  $border-color: green;
  $border-size: 2px;
  $animation-speed: .4s;
  
  &.is-selected {
    &:before,
    &:after,
    > div:before,
    > div:after {
      background: $border-color;
      content: '';
      display: block;
      position: absolute;
    }

      &:before {
        width: $border-size;
        top: 0;
        right: 0;
        animation: lineFillVert $animation-speed ease forwards;
      }

      &:after {
        height: $border-size;
        right: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        animation: lineFillHorz $animation-speed ease forwards;
        animation-delay: .1s;
      }

    > div {

      &:before {
        width: $border-size;
        bottom: 0;
        left: 0;
        animation: lineFillVert $animation-speed ease forwards;
        animation-delay: .2s;
      }

      &:after {
        height: $border-size;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        animation: lineFillHorz $animation-speed ease forwards;
        animation-delay: .3s;
      }
    }
  }
  
  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="box">
  <div></div>
</div>
```

I'm unsure how to implement this with html, css and js.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Just remove the click event and use the below code  $('.box').toggleClass('is-selected');

Answer (score 2):

Just add the class `is-selected` directly to the div.

```
<div class="box is-selected">
  <div></div>
</div>
```

You don't need to use `javascript` unless you still wanna use the click event.

**See code snippet:**

```css
@-webkit-keyframes lineFillHorz {
  from {
    width: 0;
  }
  to {
    width: 100%;
  }
}

@keyframes lineFillHorz {
  from {
    width: 0;
  }
  to {
    width: 100%;
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes lineFillVert {
  from {
    height: 1px;
  }
  to {
    height: 100%;
  }
}

@keyframes lineFillVert {
  from {
    height: 1px;
  }
  to {
    height: 100%;
  }
}

.box {
  border: 1px solid #ececec;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: block;
  width: 400px;
  height: 260px;
  margin: 2em auto;
  position: relative;
}

.box.is-selected:before,
.box.is-selected:after,
.box.is-selected>div:before,
.box.is-selected>div:after {
  background: green;
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
}

.box.is-selected:before {
  width: 2px;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  -webkit-animation: lineFillVert 0.4s ease forwards;
  animation: lineFillVert 0.4s ease forwards;
}

.box.is-selected:after {
  height: 2px;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  -webkit-animation: lineFillHorz 0.4s ease forwards;
  animation: lineFillHorz 0.4s ease forwards;
  -webkit-animation-delay: .1s;
  animation-delay: .1s;
}

.box.is-selected>div:before {
  width: 2px;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  -webkit-animation: lineFillVert 0.4s ease forwards;
  animation: lineFillVert 0.4s ease forwards;
  -webkit-animation-delay: .2s;
  animation-delay: .2s;
}

.box.is-selected>div:after {
  height: 2px;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  -webkit-animation: lineFillHorz 0.4s ease forwards;
  animation: lineFillHorz 0.4s ease forwards;
  -webkit-animation-delay: .3s;
  animation-delay: .3s;
}
```

```html
<div class="box is-selected">
  <div></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace the JavaScript with:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('.box').toggleClass('is-selected');
});
```

**Snippet**

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('.box').toggleClass('is-selected');
});
```

```css
@-webkit-keyframes lineFillHorz {
  from {
    width: 0;
  }
  to {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
@keyframes lineFillHorz {
  from {
    width: 0;
  }
  to {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes lineFillVert {
  from {
    height: 1px;
  }
  to {
    height: 100%;
  }
}
@keyframes lineFillVert {
  from {
    height: 1px;
  }
  to {
    height: 100%;
  }
}
.box {
  border: 1px solid #ececec;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: block;
  width: 400px;
  height: 260px;
  margin: 2em auto;
  position: relative;
}
.box.is-selected:before, .box.is-selected:after,
.box.is-selected > div:before,
.box.is-selected > div:after {
  background: green;
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
}
.box.is-selected:before {
  width: 2px;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  -webkit-animation: lineFillVert 0.4s ease forwards;
          animation: lineFillVert 0.4s ease forwards;
}
.box.is-selected:after {
  height: 2px;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  -webkit-animation: lineFillHorz 0.4s ease forwards;
          animation: lineFillHorz 0.4s ease forwards;
  -webkit-animation-delay: .1s;
          animation-delay: .1s;
}
.box.is-selected > div:before {
  width: 2px;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  -webkit-animation: lineFillVert 0.4s ease forwards;
          animation: lineFillVert 0.4s ease forwards;
  -webkit-animation-delay: .2s;
          animation-delay: .2s;
}
.box.is-selected > div:after {
  height: 2px;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  -webkit-animation: lineFillHorz 0.4s ease forwards;
          animation: lineFillHorz 0.4s ease forwards;
  -webkit-animation-delay: .3s;
          animation-delay: .3s;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="box">
  <div></div>
</div>
```